# Javascript with iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have two iframe in single page now first  iframe is URL is outside from host e.g www.google.com and second in local means contact.html now both having same JavaScript function e.g  `hello function()` now which will first call ?

Comment: I think you have to explain the problem a bit more. In general: The JavaScript of the iframe that loads faster will be executed first.

Comment: paste your code, or we can't catch you.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the problem is. Could you provide some html code to clarify?

Comment: i find solution my self. both frame are independent from each other and so we can call function from their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Neither will be called unless you call them. So it depends on when you call them.

If the call is inline in the page, then the one in the outer page will probably be called first, simply because it gets a head start.

Since they exist in different documents, neither will overwrite the other. Since the documents are on different hosts, [neither can be overwritten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) from the other document.

Comment: if i add in httphandler then which will call first ?

Answer (score 0):

1) only the code from same domain will be executed by other page from same domain
2) any function with the same name in another domain will have to be executed by a script from that domain

It will for sure not be the SAME function that is executed and if the function is blocking (like an alert) it will be a matter of which page loads first

Answer (score 0):

I believe neither. You have to actually reference the iframe if you want to call a function in it:

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.myFunc();
```

Bare in mind you WILL NOT be able to access anything in an iframe unless **it's of the same origin** as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

depends.

For instance

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  hello();
</script>
<iframe src='www.google.com'></iframe>
```

You page's hello function is definitely called first.

```
<iframe src='www.google.com'></iframe>
  .... more stuff
<script type='text/javascript'>
  hello();
</script>
```

In this case, you can't predict since the iframe content is loaded asynchronously and might or might not fire before your page's hello call. If you are planning however to access the values returned these function across the iframe, you might run into browser security restrictions. In any case, post some code.